# How to multiple column/row names and obtain value for that intersection in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to teach myself R, and am struggling with a value-based problem I found.

I have a matrix of values (a 4x4 table) where the rows are labeled A=1,2,3,4 and columns are B=5,6,7,8. Each intersection has a certain value (so at A=1, B=5 there's a value of 0.05 and so on), so there's 16 values.

How would I go about obtaining certain values at an intersection with value C? C would be the multiplication of A and B. So if I'm looking for C(24), I'm looking for the value at A(4)*B(6) intersection.

I'm trying to get the values for the intersection for all values, so I'm trying to get the value at (A=1, B=4), (A=1, B=5) and so on. I've tried the `match` command, relabeling column/row names, and intersect to no avail.

```
tyrcapta<-matrix(c(0.011, 0.456, 0.532, 0.456, etc., etc., etc),nrow=4)
row.names(data)<-c("A=1","A=2","A=3", "A=4")
colnames(data)<-c("B=5","B=6","B=7","B=8")
```

I expected to make a matrix, which I did. 
I set up row names and column names, which worked. 
I'm lost on how to properly proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exactly what you are asking but it seems that you are trying to extract specific values from two matrices and multiply them together. Here is a short example:

```
R> a = matrix(rnorm(16), ncol=4)
R> b = matrix(rnorm(16), ncol=4)
R> a
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
[1,]  2.7812 -0.3851 -1.2311 -1.0517
[2,] -1.6022 -1.4263  0.1320  0.9695
[3,] -0.5482 -0.4218  0.4396  0.7254
[4,]  0.4187 -0.8594  0.4404 -1.1221
R> b
         [,1]      [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
[1,]  0.68834  2.174825  0.2431  0.3075
[2,] -0.03356  0.733730  1.0273 -0.8022
[3,] -1.78209 -0.004129 -0.1408 -0.2317
[4,]  0.09620 -0.866053 -0.7647 -1.3737
R> a[2,3] * b[1,1]
[1] 0.09086
```

The [help page for matrix](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) may also be of help (also can be found by typing `?matrix` at the prompt)